# Using a View to Populate a Dataset

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to populate a Dataset in WinForms using a SQL View? I' I'm using SQLite so a stored procedure isn't an option in this particular case, so I created a view with the data that I need. However, when writing my code like I would when using a table, I get the error *"no such table: ReportDates"* on the line **adapter.Fill(ds, "ReportDates");**. Is there a way to reference it differently so it's identified as a View or is this not possible?

My code is like this:

```
    private void PopulateReportPeriodDropDown()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(sqlcs.ConnectionString()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string stm = "SELECT * FROM ReportDates";

            using (SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(stm, conn))
            {
                adapter.Fill(ds, "ReportDates");

                DataRow newRow = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
                newRow["DateIndex"] = 0;
                newRow["DateDescription"] = "-- Select Reporting Period --";
                ds.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);

                reportingPeriodDropDown.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                reportingPeriodDropDown.ValueMember = "DateIndex";
                reportingPeriodDropDown.DisplayMember = "DateDescription";

                reportingPeriodDropDown.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

I guess one option would be to create a temp table using the data in the view, then fill the dataset with that data, then drop the temp table. Though that seems like a messy way of doing things.

**EDIT:** I should mention that this code does work correctly when I reference a table name, just not when I'm trying to reference a view.

Comment: I'm testing with a Sql server provider, not with SqlLite, and it works. Are you sure that the db file have a view called ReportDates? Run `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master;` to check if the view is there

Comment: @AlejandroPérezFals Testing directly in the database it works correctly. If I run the query `SELECT * FROM ReportDates` in SQLLiteStudio then it does return data as expected. If I copy that same command to my C# code where shown above, it returns the error that the table doesn't exist. I ran the command you listed and I am seeing it shown as  name=ReportDates and tbl_name=ReportDates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database must have been corrupt in this case. I ended up completely deleting and recreating it from scratch, and now everything is working as expected.